# What's the name of my development database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

How do I find out the name of my development database in a Rails 4 app?

I need it to perform `heroku pg:transfer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name should be in your `config/database.yml`

```
development:
  database: THIS_WOULD_BE_YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE_NAME
```